# Behaviour of stdout and printf

Tags: c, printf

Just see the below program,

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    printf("hai");
    while(1);
}
```

The above code is not printing hai and its just waitinG. But if I add

```
printf("hai\n");
```

its working.

Can I know what happening internally?

Comment: What's "*nd*", please?

Comment: [The `stdout` stream is buffered, so will only display what's in the buffer after it reaches a newline (or when it's told to)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1716296/why-does-printf-not-flush-after-the-call-unless-a-newline-is-in-the-format-strin).

Comment: You could alternatively use `fflush(stdout);`. See [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fflush/).

Comment: By the way, the program is not waiting (as you wrote) at `while(1);`, it is infinitely looping. If you want the application to wait for a certain time, you can use `sleep()` or `usleep()`, if you want to wait for a key pressed, use something like `getchar()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Writing `printf("hai\n");` instead will cause, due to the newline character, the output buffer to be *flushed*, so you'll see the output before entering the infinite loop. There are other ways of flushing the output buffer, but appending the newline character is particularly simple.

Technically the behaviour of a tight loop like `while(1);` is *undefined* in C, but that is unlikely to be the cause of your problem.

Answer (score 0):

`printf("hai");` won't show something immediateley, you need to flush `stdout`'s buffer with either `printf("\n");` or `fflush(stdout);`

Answer (score 0):

Your standart output stream (stdout) is buffered, so it will only flush (and display what is in it) when it is either manually forced or when it recieves a newline character (`'\n'`).

You can change this behavior with the library function [setbuf()](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_setbuf.htm)

You can also manually flush the buffer (force it to immideatly display whats currently in it) by using `fflush(stdout);`